# Visual Studio: Execute custom code on build and/or publish

Tags: visual-studio, build

Is it possible to have Visual Studio execute code of my design upon a build and/or publish?

What I'm trying to accomplish is similar to what it does with web.config transforms.  I have a JSON file that needs some modification depending on which build configuration is used, but it's not as simple as just "replace file x with file y," it's doing an transformation of the JSON file itself.  I've devised a way of doing the transformation, and I'm hoping I can get Visual Studio to execute the code that does this transformation as part of the build process.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** I actually need to do this on *Publish* moreso than build, but if that's not possible, I'll settle for the build.

Comment: Did you try with PostBuild actions? Well you may code a Custom Tool (like .resx "compiler", for example) but it may pretty overkill...

Comment: If you're referring to the "Post-build event command line" option in the project properties, then I'm *aware* of that option, but I feel like creating an executable for this is sort of overkill.  I also need to be able to feed data into it--specifically the configuration name--which I'm not sure if I can do with that option.

Comment: Well something you have to create (DLL or EXE)...also a batch if you want. Yes you can pass parameters and you can use `$(ConfigurationName)` macro (but also others).